# Как сохранить тепловую карту в файл pdf

Tags: python, pdf

Имеется код тепловой карты на python:

```
diagrama2 = df4.pivot_table(
                    index='New',    # Строки
                    columns='Data',  # Колонки
                    values='Value',  # Значения
                    aggfunc=sum).fillna(0).applymap(int)
plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))
plt.title(s, size = 16)    # Заголовок тепловой карты
sns.heatmap(diagrama2, annot=True, fmt="", linewidths=.5, linecolor='white', square=True, cmap="OrRd")
```

Как её выгрузить в новый pdf файл?

Comment: `plt.savefig("diagrama2.pdf")`

Comment: пустой лист получается...

Comment: А на экран если вывести показывается?

Comment: Да, показывается )

Answer (score 1):

Для сохранения используется метод `plt.savefig`. Если показывается пустое изображение, попробуйте проверить на простом примере:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn

arr = np.random.random_sample((10, 10))
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
seaborn.heatmap(arr)
plt.savefig("test.pdf")
plt.show()
```

Изображение будет сохранено в pdf в текущей директории. Также изображение будет выведено на экран, если у вас установлен бэкенд, который позволяет отображать на экране.

Comment: О, это работает. Спасибо!